# Filter data from a complex json object with jq

Tags: json, kubernetes, jq

I have to extract each data from configMaps of a Kubernetes cluster which respond to certain criteria. I try to do it with jq but I can't get over it ...

Here is my k8s extraction :

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "data": {
                "DATA_1": false,
                "DATA_2": "http://my-cluster-dns.my-service:8080",
                "DATA_3": 200
            },
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "cluster-agent-config",
                "namespace": "my-namespace",
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "data": {
                "agent-log.yaml": "log-level: INFO\nmax-filesize-mb: 50\nmax-backups: 5\nwrite-to-stdout: true"
            },
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "cluster-agent-log",
                "namespace": "your-namespace",             
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "data": {
                "agent-monitoring.yml": "metric-collection-interval-seconds: 30\ncluster-metric-collection-interval-seconds: 60\nmetadata-collection-interval-seconds: 60\ncontainer-registration-batch-size: 5\npod-registration-batch-size: 6\nmetric-upload-retry-count: 2\nmetric-upload-retry-interval-milliseconds: 5\nmax-pods-to-register-count: 750\nmax-pod-logs-tail-lines-count: 500\ninstrumentation-max-polling-attempts: 10\npod-filter: {}\nns-to-monitor-regex: \".*\""
            },
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "cluster-agent-mon",
                "namespace": "his-namespace",
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "data": {
                "DATA_1": "http://my-cluster-dns.my-service:9000",
                "DATA_2": "something",
            },
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "cluster-agent-misc",
                "namespace": "her-namespace",
            }
        }
    ],
    "kind": "List",
    "metadata": {
        "resourceVersion": ""
    }
}
```

I would like to have something like that in output (csv) :

```
my-namespace,cluster-agent-config,DATA_2,http://my-cluster-dns.my-service:8080
her-namespace,cluster-agent-misc,DATA_1,http://my-cluster-dns.my-service:9000
```

The criteria here was "the data contains an url beginning with http://my-cluster-dns".

I achieve to get the values I am looking for but I lost the other metadata (and the corresponding keys) ... For example with this jq statement `jq -r '.items[].data[] | select(contains("http://my-cluster-dns"))'`

Or I can get the other metadata but the filter applies on them too (and for certain criteria, this doesn't fill my needs) for exemple with this one `jq -r '.items[] | . as $item | .data[] | $item.metadata.name, $item.metadata.namespace, . | select(contains("http://my-cluster-dns"))'`

Finally, I think I'm close with this : `.items[] | . as $item | .data[] | [{ name: $item.metadata.name, namespace: $item.metadata.namespace, value: . }]` but I can't find the way to filter correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way that uses `to_entries` to access key and value, and stores it in a variable for later:

```bash
.items[] | (
  .data | to_entries[]
  | select(.value | strings | startswith("http://my-cluster-dns"))
) as $data
| [.metadata.namespace, .metadata.name, $data.key, $data.value]
| join(",") # or @csv
```

```
my-namespace,cluster-agent-config,DATA_2,http://my-cluster-dns.my-service:8080
her-namespace,cluster-agent-misc,DATA_1,http://my-cluster-dns.my-service:9000
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WRICu7japHb)

Note: For proper escaping (and quoting), use `@csv` instead of `join(",")`.

Comment: not "perfect" ^^, I got the following error for some extracts :

`jq: error (at <stdin>:3900): null (null) has no keys`

I don't know why yet...

Comment: OK, I get it, it's because some of my configMaps have `binaryData` instead of `data`. I correct it with this : `.items[] | select(has("data")) | (
  .data | to_entries[]
  | select(.value | strings | startswith("http://my-cluster-dns"))
) as $data
| [.metadata.namespace, .metadata.name, $data.key, $data.value | gsub("\n"; "\\n")]
| @csv`
(I took the opportunity to replace new line in values)